# Send program's serial output to pseudo-terminal used by serial sniffer such as jpnevulator

Tags: tty, serial-port, hard-link

1. I am running an application that communicates through a real serial port `e.g. /dev/ttyS0` to a remote device.  I can configure this application to use `/dev/ttyS0`, `/dev/ttyS1`, etc., by passing the numeric suffix to the program, not the fully-qualified name.
2. I would like to sniff the traffic going through this serial port using something like `jpnevulator`.  This `jpnevulator` opens a pseudo-terminal to which the application to be monitored is supposed to connect.

Is there any way to re-assign the name of the ports, for example `/dev/ttyS1` to an actual pseudo-terminal such as `/dev/pty/23`, so that the application transparently connects to `/dev/pty/23` via `/dev/ttyS1`?  Would a file link `ln` achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would just edit the binary and replace the `/dev/ttyS%d` or similar string with `/dev/ptyX%d` (taking care that the replacement have the same length as the original), then create a symlink `/dev/ptyX0` to the path of the slave end of the pseudo-terminal.

There are a lot of other solutions, more or less awkward:

a) if your system is linux, temporarily `mount --bind /dev/pts/<pty used by the sniffer> /dev/ttyS2` (and connect your program to the serial line `2`)

b) similarly, move `/dev/ttyS2` out of the way and replace it with a link to the pty

c) run it inside qemu and redirect the serial port of the vm to the pty

d) some fake paths/filesystem solution using `LD_PRELOAD`

e) namespaces, unionfs, chroots, etc

Comment: I actually tried the symbolic link approach and the program barfed up an error message - "incorrect parameter" or something like that.  I suspect that the program is setting up serial-port specific parameters that don't map well to the pseudo-terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions.  I will try those when I get a chance.